# No applications I have downloaded will open

Tags: unity, vlc, kodi

My Kodi, VLC, even transmission will not open and show the display...It's like it thinks it's open but nothing is showing on the screen. Any help?
I have tried reinstalling unity with:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: I think I have read something in "known bugs section"  that the installed apps log is not updated correctly in some cases. I can't find it now. I think there was a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I found it...

Look at this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes/

They have written:

Sometimes doesn't update apps to "Installed" after installation via search https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1551599